# Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.6.1055.0, time stamp: 0x563c12de

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, cloud, iis-8, iaas

Trying to launch Iaas IIS hosted asp.net application. getting below error.
any idea please?

Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x5215df96
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.6.1055.0, time stamp: 0x563c12de
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0000000000009780
Faulting process id: 0x3b8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d28eb490fe4237
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: d7320ef8-faa7-11e6-80dc-000d3af785ff
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of code session is looping infinity. i spent hell amount of time.